# Lying to receive money

Tags: gezel-stealing, noachide-laws, sheker-false

Is a ben Noah allowed to lie to a Christian in order to get money from him? Or is it considered as stealing ?

Edit: I've got an answer from a rabbi, who said it's prohibited since it is like tricking his mind in order to get "illegally" something from him.

Comment: You already answered your own question. But why would you think it's permitted?

Comment: Why would a Christian be different than any other nonJew in this respect?

Comment: I think the real question here is whether the prohibition of [Lo Sachmod](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84710/) is relevant to non-Jews. I agree with the other comments - all non-Jews are equal in respect to the seven laws. But I’m pretty sure that Lo Sachmod doesn’t apply to non-Jews, in which case I’m surprised at your Rabbi’s ruling. On an unrelated note, I’m going to go ahead and edit to remove the first-person in your question, to prevent anyone from wanting to close this as practical Halacha. If you don’t like my edit, feel free to edit over it or roll it back.

Comment: @DonielF no, gezel is gezel.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Thats my point - I’m not sure lying or pressuring someone is technically gezeirah, not to say that it isn’t assur.

Comment: @DonielF Saifer haChinuch in your link said it is but what does lo sachmod have to do with getting money for words

Comment: @hazoriz The guy is willingly giving up his money. Therefore it is not gezeilah. You are causing him to give up his money. Therefore it is chemdah.